# Using MSID/MID with leaflet to display Google My Maps data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-maps, kmz

I'm wondering if there is a way to display MSID/MID with leaflet.

I found this forum below;
[Any way I can load KML data from Google maps (again) via JS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458329/any-way-i-can-load-kml-data-from-google-maps-again-via-js-api)

KMZs work fantastically with the arcgis and google API (kmlLayer) but I can't seem to find any information on using a kmz with leaflet.
I'd prefer not having to Unzip locally, and omnivore does not appear to work with KMZs.

Comment: Also found this Question/Answer [Using KMZ files with OpenLayers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633960/using-kmz-files-with-openlayers).

Comment: Is your issue with using a google My Maps URL for a KMZ file (with `kml?mid=...`, for instance) in Leaflet, or loading KMZ files generally? I'm not sure that using a My Maps URL is possible from a non-Google map, since (at least when I try this) there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow access from non-Google domains. If you want to load a KMZ file with Omnivore, you will probably have to unzip it first using something like [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html) and then use Omnivore's `.kml.parse` method on the result.

Comment: using the my maps url (.kmz).

Comment: I was able to use the mid with ArcGis API - https://jsfiddle.net/jyveslandry/4ujfgjky/  and  google api https://jsfiddle.net/jyveslandry/ose0s5d1/

Comment: Thanks Nathan I'll try JSZip, do you know of any examples where this has been done?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got any solutions for accessing KMZ files via a My Maps MSID/MID in Leaflet. However, in general, to load a KMZ file in Leaflet, you can use [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) (along with the [`getBinaryContent` method](http://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/documentation/api/getbinarycontent.html) of [JSZipUtils](https://github.com/stuk/jszip-utils)) to extract the KML, then [Leaflet Omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) to parse the result.

JSZip will produce an object containing all the files in an archive, and you can select an individual file either by name or with the [`file(regex)` method](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_regex.html). You can use `file(/.*\.kml/)[0]` to select the first file with a `.kml` extension. Then to read the file as text, you would use either the `asText` method ([in version 2.x](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/v2.6.0/documentation/api_zipobject.md) of JSZip) or the `async("string")` method ([in version 3.x](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_zipobject/async.html)). Once you have the kml as text, you can use Leaflet Omnivore's `.kml.parse` method to read it into a Leaflet layer. For version 2.x (which I find more straightforward), the whole thing would look like this:

```
var kmzUrl = *your URL here*;

JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(kmzUrl, function(e, d) {
  try {
    var z = new JSZip(d);
    var k = z.file(/.*\.kml/)[0].asText();
    var p = omnivore.kml.parse(k).addTo(map);
    p.eachLayer(function(layer){
      layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.description); //or whatever
    })
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
});
```

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/26vagt77/

For version 3.x, it would look like this:

```
var kmzUrl = *your URL here*;

JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(kmzUrl, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    alert(err);
    return;
  }
  try {
    JSZip.loadAsync(data)
      .then(function(zip) {
        return zip.file(/.*\.kml/)[0].async("string");
      })
      .then(function success(text) {
          var p = omnivore.kml.parse(text).addTo(map);
          p.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.description); //or whatever
          });
        },
        function error(e) {
          alert(e);
        });
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/adxcapeo/

Comment: Thanks Nathan that definitely does the job.  I also found a work around see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37311185/4346433.  You then avoid using JSzip.

Comment: Your answer seems to have been deleted, but I was able to see it before it disappeared. The trick was to add `&forcekml=1` to the URL, correct? If you found a workaround for loading the My Maps URLs directly in Leaflet, you should probably post that here as an answer too.